# dotfill in table of index

Tags: tables

I am in the process of making a table which looks like as follows:

[image]

However, I am unable to get the required output. That is two columns aligned left and right filled to full page width and separated by dots with proper alignment along with "{" sign as shown.

Here is an MWE developed by me so far:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{}l}

CLASS IPER SPEC & \dotfill 5  \\
\\
SIDE FIT & \\
\\
SPLINE TYPE  & \dotfill FILLET ROOT \\
\\
NUMBER OF TEETH  & \dotfill 26 \\
\\
DIAMETRAL PITCH & \dotfill 20/30 \\
\\
MODULE & \dotfill 1.27 \\
\end{tabular*}
```

Here is the output of this code which clearly different from intended output. How can I obtain the desired output?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand what are you doing there. I think the best package for your need is [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries?lang=en).

However if you want to do it manually, you should use the environment `tabularx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\newcommand\indexgap{\tabularnewline\multicolumn{2}{l}{}\tabularnewline}
\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X<{\dotfill}l@{}l}
    CLASS IPER SPEC  & 5 \indexgap
    SIDE FIT & \indexgap
    SPLINE TYPE    & FILLET ROOT \indexgap
    NUMBER OF TEETH    & 26 \indexgap
    DIAMETRAL PITCH  & 20/30 \indexgap
    MODULE  & 1.27 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{0.9\textwidth}l@{}l}

    CLASS IPER SPEC \dotfill & 5  \\
    \\
    SIDE FIT \dotfill & \\
    \\
    SPLINE TYPE   \dotfill & \\
    FILLET ROOT \dotfill \\
    \\
    NUMBER OF TEETH   \dotfill & 26 \\
    \\
    DIAMETRAL PITCH  \dotfill & 20/30 \\
    \\
    MODULE  \dotfill & 1.27 \\
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```